# swift spritekit update not getting accurate or constant reading

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, updates

Im using update to track my moving node. However when using the update function it Is not getting the constant or accurate numbers.

what my code is doing is first it declares its current position and endpostion. Then the node moves.In the Update function I track the nodes position whiles its moving. If it reaches the endPosition and the user did not touch the screen then it updates the endposition. And does this until the user touches the screen.

My code is doing everything I want. Except the update function jumps from reading 10.9 to like 12.7 to 30.75. This is not really constant so when the node stops, its position is offset by like 2-3 points. which I don not want.

any suggestions to make it more accurate or do the code another way?

code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    curPos=bear.position.y+(bear.size.height/2)
    endPos=bear.position.y+(boxsize+boxsize/2)
    print(curPos,endPos)

    let moveUp=SKAction.moveBy(x:0,y:boxsize,duration:0.7)
    let rep=SKAction.repeatForever(moveUp)
    bear.run(rep)
}
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    count=bear.position.y

    if endPos <= count {
        endPos=count+boxsize
        print(endPos)

        if touchz==1{
            bear.removeAllActions()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you getting your numbers, and are you checking your update.  Update is not a constant 60 FPS.  You may have something that is locking the main thread causing the update to happen less than 60FPS, or you are on simulator which is very slow

Comment: yes, Im on a simulator. Im getting the numbers by using print(count) which is in the update function. I did not put that in the code I posted. However if i use my phone it is still not constant and has a offset . Do you suggest I use something else besides update?

Comment: do `print("CT:\(currentTime), CNT:\(count)" )`

Comment: oh, LOL duh, of course your numbers are jumping,  you are adding absolute values, not a difference.  You should be printing the count to see where you are at, not the endPos, and the way it is looking, you will never reach endPos

Comment: what is boxSize we need that info...

Comment: i'm unclear on exactly what you are trying to do. If you have a dedicated start position and end position, then those should be constants (not variables). In update, you just need to check bear.position.y OR curPos against the end position, and it should be 100% accurate.

Also, it appears that `count` shoud be = to curpos, not bear.position.y

Comment: curPos does not update, so this needs to be set somewhere

Comment: boxsize is 56.8, but this number is really unimportant because it can change by a randomizer. endPos is not really a constant because it will change once the bear reaches that point. I did change curPos to count but it still has an offset. And i need the number to mach by no less than 15%

Comment: what I'm trying to do is, I have a bear, I get its starting position. It moves up using an action that repeats. If the user touches the screen the bear will stop moving, but will only stop moving if it has moved by  a distance of boxsize(56.8).

Comment: I figured out why I have an offset. its because My numbers are all CGFloats and it hard to compare them exactly. To match them by no less than 15% you will have to have a tolerance. This was more of a math problem then a coding one. But thank for the help you two! @Knight0fDragon